# How Can I Access my ViewController's Property Variables From Another Class?

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting

Ok, this is really bugging me and I am sure the solution is simple...  I am unable to set my ViewController's property variables from another class (SeverConnect.m), which I have declared and synthesized properly in my ViewController's .h/.m files:

**ServerConnect.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Contact.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface ServerConnect : NSObject
{
Contact *newContact;
NSString *codeRawContent;
NSMutableArray *contactListCopy;
...  //Other variables declared here, but not shown in order to save space
```

**Inside ServerConnect.m:**

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
NSLog(@"parserDidFinish");

newContact = [[Contact alloc] initWithCodeInfo:(NSString *)codeInfo
                                       contactName:(NSString *)completeName 
                                      contactImage:(UIImage *)profileImage
                                    contactWebSite:(NSString *)codeRawContent];
[contactListCopy insertObject:newContact atIndex:0];
[ViewController setContactList:contactListCopy];  //Automatic Reference Counting Error Occurs Here: "No known class method for selector 'setContactList:'"
}
```

As I mentioned above, I have declared and synthesized the property variable, "contactList", in my ViewController's .h/.m files (with no errors):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contactList;  //In ViewController's .h file
@synthesize contactList;  //In ViewController's .m file
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to access an instance property on a class:

```
[ViewController setContactList:contactListCopy];
```

you need to first create an instance of the ViewController class, and then set its property. Something like this:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewController setContactList:contactListCopy];
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin for the fast response!  I do create an instance of the ViewController class from my AppDelegate when the app first loads ("...didFinishLaunchingWithOptions..."):
   viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
By creating another instance, won't I lose all of the data saved in the previous viewController instance (i.e. the other instance variables)?  Can't I set the contactList of the original viewController instance, which I declared previously in my AppDelegate?

Comment: yea that was just an example. If you already have the instance use that: [viewController setContactList:contactListCopy]; If you need to access it from ServerConnect.m, make it a property of the app delegate  and access it through there: [appDelegate.viewController setContactList:contactListCopy];

Comment: @JRoss and make damn sure you never use capital letters at the beginning of an instance name (viewController for instance vs. ViewController for class).

Comment: @EdwinIskandar I just so happened to make the viewController instance a property of my AppDelegate previously (similarly in its .h/.m files), but when I try your suggestion above I receive the following error: 
"Semantic Issue: Property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'"  Any ideas why it would not be finding the AppDelegate's "viewController" property?

Comment: Thanks @Till.  Do you know why I would be having trouble accessing my AppDelegate 'viewController' property instance variable from my ServerConnect.m?

Comment: @JRoss, you need to import your appDelegate class into ServerConnect.m and refer to your app delegate like this (assuming the name of your app delegate file is AppDelegate): AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

`[ViewController setContactList:contactListCopy];`

you should be using a variable of type `ViewController`. The way you are using it, it should be a class method, not a property.
Write something like:

`ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];`

`[viewController setContactList:contactListCopy];`

Comment: Thanks @Levi.  I'm still having issues, though, in accessing property variables outside of ServerConnect.m (see conversation below).

Comment: Post your .h of AppDelegate and the way you are currently trying to access the property